# Как добавить пункт в меню панели задач?

Tags: windows, winapi

Можно ли добавить пункт в меню панели задач? И как это сделать (с запуском моего обработчика, естественно)?

Хочу сделать прогу, которая добавит пункт "Приостановить"/"Возобновить" (процесс и его потоки). См. крин.

p.s. А может, уже есть такая прога?
Но в любом случае интересно как это можно сделать...

[[image: 1]]

Comment: Зачем в чужую прогу добавлять? https://superuser.com/questions/23375/windows-7-taskbar-create-popup-menus

Answer (score 2):

Эта функция называется JumpList, ее нужно использовать в коде приложения через API [ICustomDestinationList::AddUserTasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378395(v=vs.85).aspx)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/gg281362.aspx